# K-means clustering of word embedding gives strange results

Tags: nlp, clustering, word-embeddings

I'm trying to cluster words based on pre trained embeddings. I ran a simple experiment where I obtained around 100 words relating to "food taste", obtained word embeddings from a pre-trained set, and tried to run k-means on the result.

I do get sensible results on certain clusters, but very strange results on others. E.g:

```
Cluster 1: [fatty, oily, greasy] -- (good)
Cluster 2: [crumbly, powdery, grainy, flakey, chalky] -- (good)
Cluster 3: [flavorful, hearty, unflavored, savory, full-bodied] -(bad)
Cluster 4: [seasoned, unseasoned] -- (bad)
```

Can anyone suggest as to why seemingly opposite words like (seasoned, unseasoned) and (flavorful, unflavored) would be clustered together?

What I tried:

1) Using fasttext embeddings and Glove embeddings. The latest results are from concatenating fasttext wikipedia and common crawl embeddings.

2) Normalizing the vectors to same length before doing k-means (using eucledian distnaces). I think this is somewhat similar to having cosine distances. Tried not normalizing s well, but normalizing gave better results.

3) Tried some other clustring methods like DBSCAN but k-means seems better.

4) Tried PCA to reduce the dimensionality of the word vectors - didnt change the results much. Tried PCA for the selected embeddings in my vocab that needs to be clustered- not the whole word set.

Any suggestions to improve my results are welcome. If someone came across research articles discussing similar issues please post them as well.

Thanks!
TNC

Comment: Antonyms are still similar by [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics#Distributional_hypothesis), or context. If your goal is to separate them, try a different model, such as LWET: [Revisit Word Embeddings with Semantic Lexicons for Modeling Lexical Contrast](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8023397/). Welcome to the site!

Comment: Paragram-SL999 are a large set of word embeddings that get nearly human performance on a word-word similarity benchmark. You might get better results with these: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jwieting/

Answer (score 17):

Word embeddings are trained by **substitutability, not similarity**.

If you consider a sentence like "This food is unflavored." Then a good substitute word would be "flavored", and the sentence will still be "correct".

In many cases, substitutability arises from similarity (crunchy, crispy) but it *does* also arise from opposites. You may consider "king" and "queen" to be opposites, too.

You probably should use a supervised approach then.